# C++ deleting a object from it's own class

Tags: c++

I have the following situation.

```
FooClass* fooPointer = new FooClass();

int main() {
  while (/*logic*/) {
    if (fooPointer) {
      // some logic
    }
  }
}  

class FooClass {
  void fooClass::fooMethod() {
    if (/*logic*/) {
      //logic
      delete this;
    }     
  }
}
```

So I am basically deleting the object. However on the next iteration It still enters the if statement in the main method (

```
if (fooPointer) {
  // some logic
}
```

).

Why doesn't it recognize that the object has already been deleted with the null check?

Comment: `delete` doesn't set the pointer to null. It doesn't change it at all. You should rethink your design, this is the wrong road to go down.

Comment: Begs the question, why isn't the inside `// some logic` inside the while-loop determining, and then deleting `fooPointer` *there*, afterward setting it to `nullptr`? The implementation of COM objects notwithstanding, `delete this;` is nearly always a design smell.

Comment: Better to use std::unique_ptr, possibly with a custom deleter.

Comment: @WhozCraig As for your question, Because the deletion logic is inside one of the many nested methods inside the FooClass

Comment: @john I suspected, but the aroma is just as putrid. At best (and I use that term loosely, because this feels like I'm contributing to the delinquency of a bad design), the `FooClass` constructor could take a reference to a pointer-to-clear on self-destruction, retained as part of the `FooClass` instance, and nullified immediately before the `delete this;`. That's a *terrible* solution to a painted in corner. Regardless, one way or another, if you're keeping this design you *must* have a path to the external owning pointer, lest you leave it dangling, and currently you do not.

Comment: @WhozCraig anyway is the `nullptr` the only way to use it since it needs C++ 11 and when I choose C++ 11 I get some glut errors (using CodeBlocks)

Comment: @john it came along with C++11 and later. Prior to that use `NULL`.

Comment: BTW, the pointer can point to an invalid area of memory and not be `NULL` or equal to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `delete` on an object usually is doing two things:

1. It calls the destructor
2. It frees the memory of the object

It **does not** set anything to null nor does it change the value of pointers in any other means. That's why your check doesn't work.

So if you want to go this way, you somehow have to null your pointer yourself.